# Best way to generate MBeans for managing an XML File

Tags: java, xml, jmx

I have an XML file defined by an XML Schema. I need to manipulate it with Java code. I also need to enable remote clients to manipulate it via JMX.

Anyone got any good suggestions?

Comment: Manipulate XML via JMX? It sound like *manipulating MySQL via FTP*... I guess your clients aren't interested in manipulating the XML file per se. Provide them some more abstract methods that express business logic, I guess XML storage isn't actually important.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an XML file used for configuration.

1. Use JAXB to generate Java bindings
2. Use some appropriate tool to expose the Java objects generated in 1) as JMX MBeans (Spring JMX, Model MBeans, etc)